# Move all matching lines to behind first occurance of some string

Tags: vim

It must be reusable across many files. The best I've come up with is using a macro and a mark:

```
qa
gg
/target-location<CR>
mm
:g/word/move 'm<CR>
q
```

Is there some nicer way that does not involve a mark or even a macro?

At first, I thought I might manage without a mark with

```
qa
gg
/target-location<CR>
:g/word/move .<CR>
q
```

But this was a rookie mistake and did nothing, '.' refers to the position of the line being moved, not the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a mark sounds good to me:

```
:1;/target-location/km
:g/word/m'm
```

See `:help :k` and `:help :range`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to avoid excessive mode switching, as it makes your code easier to read. Also, you can spare a letter-bookmark by using automatic one.

```
:1;/target-location/k' | keepj g/word/move ''
```